# Does deletion of questions by community make a question ban "unsolvable" for a user?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, post-ban, vote-to-delete

I well know, that SO's  *question ban* algorithm isn't (and won't be) disclosed.

Well though, every time I use my deletion privileges, I ask myself:

***May this throw the OP into an unsolvable situation to lift a question ban?***

If we deleted the question, what are OP's opportunities to reactivate and improve it actually?

If it was deleted (and received downvotes), and there's simply no way to improve the question, because it was bogus beforehand, how could a user improve it?

Could users lift their question ban though, by receiving more rep from answers?

My point is, that the situation is different from OP's deleting their not well accepted questions, counting still against the for a question ban.

**Does it make a difference for question banning, if a question was deleted by either community, 3 trusted users, a mod, or the OP themselves deleted the question?**

---

For nitpickers here's a sample: [Could someone tell me what's wrong with this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30404237/could-someone-tell-me-whats-wrong-with-this-code)

Comment: Considering all that it takes to get out from the ban is to create a new account, clearly deleting their questions doesn't prevent them from getting out of the ban.  Go delete away, knowing that nothing you do will actually stop them from continuing to post more crap.

Comment: I thought deleted questions are only considered into the ban if they were deleted less than 60 days ago

Comment: @Servy _New accounts_ to replace existing ones to undergo the site policies might fire back badly?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ^ Then it's *Sherlock Holmes* time again to hunt them down and show them, that it is unfair if they ask the same question with 2 different accounts

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ One would think so.  One would, however, be wrong.  That is, if all the person is interested in is asking questions, and not how many Imaginary Internet Points they have.

Comment: @Rizier123 Penalizing the account (that they don't care about at all) after they've already gotten exactly what they wan't isn't exactly an effective deterrent.

Comment: @Servy No, I mean if someone creates more than 1 account to *cheat* (voting, asking same question over and over) that we should show them, that this is: 1. not how SO works 2. unfair against all other users, which also asked a question and waiting for an answer

Comment: @Servy _" One would, however, be wrong. That is, if all the person is interested in is asking questions, and not how many Imaginary Internet Points they have."_ Well a good point. While keeping the site cleqaner by throwing out their crap questions, we simply shouldn't care about effects (question ban) that count towards that user. They'll find a way undergoing the SO engine anyways?

Comment: @Rizier123 Okay.  Then they ignore you because they don't care, they just want whatever it is that they're trying to get from the multiple accounts, and keep on doing it.  You think telling people like that that it's not how the site is supposed to work, or that it harms other users, is something they would care about in the least?

Comment: @Servy ((Not really :)), but from a objective perspective I always go with the assumption: "yes". (But I also flag such behaviour , so if they care or not, they know it now and the mods will handle it)

Comment: Bad is the 'OP themselves' question deletion is not always (!) possible, but it should be (maybe not if  stack-overflow is protecting the knowledge gathered from that question)

Comment: Isn't there some sort of probationary period user can go on to start asking questions again?

Comment: @DieterLücking _" 'OP themselves' question deletion is not always (!) possible, but it should be ..."_ No I'm disagreeing about that point. To be clear I've been talking about already closed questions, and if to delete vote or not.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm actually asking about the effects on question ban, and if there
's a difference about community/mod closed questions or the OP deleted it themselves.

Answer (score 3):

It's not unsolvable.

Firstly, as has been pointed out in the comments, they can simply abandon that account and start afresh. This isn't a problem unless they start using the 2<sup>nd</sup> account to up-vote the first in an effort to get it out of the ban. However, if they have taken note of why their questions weren't well received and start posting good questions, well that's a win.

Secondly, the older the question the less it counts towards the ban, so eventually the ban will age away. I have no idea how long this process will take though.

Comment: Hm. Wasn't the ban (and rate-limiting) formula changed so simply waiting has no effect?

Comment: @Deduplicator - I thought it was the other way round - of course I could have misunderstood what I read, but I'm fairly sure that it was changed to give people a second chance.

Comment: Your statement about questions mattering less toward the ban as time goes on seems to contradict [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584/6471538) FAQ answer, which says "Automatic bans never expire or 'time out'. This means that you cannot simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action, you will never be allowed to post again.".